# Fixed-Green -square on 4K Display Asus n551VW

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-display, 4k-resolution

Today i notice my new Asusn551VW has some problem with display.
I witness a *small green square on my display* when the *background is pure black*, the problem looks more clear when the system starts up.
i installed the latest graphic display driver, but the problem remains.
when i connect my laptop to external monitor, i don't see any green square any more.
i upload a picture focusing on the problem.
i want to know the root of problem, and could this square get larger over the time?

I upload a picture of my laptop screen focusing on the problem.
[image]

Comment: If it's new, I recommend visiting the dealer. The easiest way would be to get a replacement laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible for us to tell you the exact root cause. The obvious would be physical damage from the screen being impacted by an object. The less obvious possibilities are **stuck pixels** or a **residual image** issue.

Regarding the later two possibilities, yes, it is possible for it to get larger. It is also possible for it to be fixed. There are several techniques that can be employed to attempt to resolve each type of problem.

Here is a good article that explains what I am referring to - [Addressing common problems with LCD displays](http://www.cnet.com/news/addressing-common-problems-with-lcd-displays/).

*Note: You did not ask how to resolve the problem, so search out the method of your choosing.*